# Am I correct in understanding that vector printing in SilverLight 5 will only work with a Postscript printer?

Tags: silverlight, printing, silverlight-5.0

I had read some blogs about SilverLight 5 and find it hard to believe what I read!

> That even on Windows,  SilverLight 5 will only do vector (high
>   quality) printing to a postscript printer.

(Also happened to XML Paper becoming  the format that all print drivers understood on windows…)

Answer (score 3):

I found [Silverlight 5: Vector and Bitmap Printing for Reports and more](http://10rem.net/blog/2011/06/11/silverlight-5-vector-and-bitmap-printing-for-reports-and-more) to be quite helpful regarding PostScript printing in Silverlight 5.

In particular:

> If your content or your printer doesn't support PostScript printing,
>   Silverlight automatically falls back to sending an uncompressed bitmap
>   to the printer. If your printer doesn't support PostScript, you'll see
>   the effect of opacity in the printed results (some items lighter
>   colored than others, for example) as the fallback bitmap mode supports
>   opacity.

I take it that Silverlight 5 will still print to PCL printers but there may be a degradation in quality.

Comment: Yep, it still prints everywhere.. just doesn't give you the Vector Printing.. (it falls back to what Silverlight 4 had)

Answer (score 1):

As an additional note, I ran into some issues where a printer had an incompatible PostScript driver, or a driver with PostScript emulation. In this case they were printing out garbled PDFs. I was able to come up with a solution to force bitmap printing in Silverlight 5 by using a PrintDocument and handling the PrintPage event.

If you are having garbling/printing issues in Silverlight 5, this thread may be helpful:
[Silverlight 5 printing garbled Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10114460/silverlight-5-printing-garbled-reports/10352124#10352124)